# Dynamic libraries passed to the linker as absolute paths being loaded by relative path?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, rpath

I'm attempting to build and run a project I'm working on. I go ahead and build and everything's wonderful, no errors of any sort. Then when I try to run an executable, I get an error message that some of the dynamic library dependencies could not be found:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libgpr.dylib
  Referenced from: ./test-exec
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Interesting. What does `otool -l` report?

```
... snip ...
Load command 11
       cmd LC_MAIN
   cmdsize 24
  entryoff 1247184
 stacksize 0
Load command 12
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 104
         name /abs/path/to/libprotobuf.10.dylib (offset 24) <--- The same path as passed to the linker
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 19:00:02 1969
      current version 11.0.0
compatibility version 11.0.0
Load command 13
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 40
         name libgpr.dylib (offset 24)     <--- Note the local path
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 19:00:02 1969
      current version 0.0.0
compatibility version 0.0.0
```

What gives? My build invocation is (after some cleanup), as emitted by CMake:

Compile (newlines for readability)

```
cd /path/to/project && /path/to/c++ 
   -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -g -fPIE 
-I/path/to/project -I/googletest/headers 
-I/googlemock/headers 
-I/path/to/project/usr/include 
-I/include 
-I/path/to/jni/Contents/Home/include
-I/path/to/jni/Home/include/darwin
-std=gnu++11 -o test-exec.o -c
/path/to/project/test-exec.cc
```

Link:

```
cd /path/to/project && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.2.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test-exec.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/path/to/c++   
-Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -g 
-Wl,-search_paths_first
-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  
test-exec.o  -o test-exec
/path/to/libprotobuf.dylib 
/path/to/libgpr.dylib
/path/to/libgrpc.dylib
/path/to/libgrpc++.dylib
../../dep1.a
../../dep2.a
/path/to/libgmock.a
/path/to/libgmock_main.a 
/path/to/libgtest_main.a
```

As far as I can tell, both `libprotobuf.dylib` and `libgpr.dylib` are being passed in as absolute paths during the link stage. How come `libprotobuf.dylib` gets loaded by absolute path and not `libgpr.dylib`?

For what it's worth, setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` makes it work, but I don't want to have to set it or export it. I've set up my repo to build all dependencies and place them into a specific directory, it should be just clone-and-build.

My compiler version is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: `otool -D lib_file`   what does it say? This print the name of the lib. I expect one in one case has the full path, the other only the filename

Comment: Indeed, `libprotobuf` outputs an absolute path to itself, whereas `libgpr` outputs only its filename.

Comment: Then, this is the issue. The library has been built with only the relative name. You can use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or you can try something with `install_name_tool` if you don't have access to the source code of the library

Comment: This is a good observation. However, when I changed the install name using `install_name_tool` to the absolute path and rebuilt my code, I get the same problem.

Comment: I don't understood. Do you compile the library or somebody gave it to you?

Comment: Have you tried `install_name_tool -id new_absolute_file_name.dylib oldLib.dylib` ? I tried on a library and it changed the name of the library.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently. Using `install_name_tool` after building the dylib fixed the problem; however, the version of clang I'm using accepts an `-install_name` parameter which lets me rename the dylib I'm building (I used `-install_name @rpath/<name>.dylib`). `otool -D <name>.dylib` confirmed the corrected name. Once the main program was linked against this newly built dylib, `otool -l <exe>` showed the correctly updated path (`@rpath/<name>.dylib` in my case), and the dylib was correctly found at runtime.